FLux Query with stateDuration. It does not seem to disaplay the actual duration of the change of state
I wrote this code on InfluxDB UI:
from(bucket: "name_undisclosed")
  |> range(start: -10h)
  |> filter(fn: (r) => r["_measurement"] == "merge_requests")
  |> filter(fn: (r) => r["_field"] == "state")
  |> group(columns: ["project"])
  |> stateDuration(fn: (r) => r.state == "merged", column: "duration", unit: 1s)

In the resulting table I get a column full of "-1" values but when I look at the actual database there are time gaps between the first opened and the merged state of a project. Is there anything I should add?
I Basically was trying to set up duration of the merged done in the GitHub. I tried different types of queries like filtering r.state == "opened" or r.state == "merged"  but nothing worked. Please advice.

You should show more details, like what's you data, and what is your expect output
